# Check changes in models in MongoDB, SailsJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, models

I am creating an application in Node JS and Sails JS. Here I have a model AppVersion which contains version of the application. I want to check continuously whether any value is getting updated in the DB. If it is updated, I need to give a response to client. This checking must be done whenever app is open. How can i do this? Here is my code for AppVersion model.

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        version: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    }
};
```

Please help me fixing this issues. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This a standard thing if you have a connection with a client through websockets:

```
 io.socket.on("<model name>", listenerFunction)
```

See more in the docs:
http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub

Comment: I tried the same. But suppose I am changing the model directly from browser and someone is working in the app, will this work? Sockets are different right?

Comment: It should work, but ofcourse errors may happen, you have to watch for these both in your back-end and front-end. But I havent done anything big with WebSockets yet, so maybe someone else should elaborate on this.

Comment: If updation and watch is done in same socket, it will work. But if updation is done in one and watch is done in another, then it's not working

Comment: You have to subscribe to an instance if you want to receive notifications about it.  The socket that's causing the update is probably getting subscribed earlier when it retrieves the instance.  Check out the documentation that @MartinMalinda posted.